# Calculate the ratio between different column, with some restrictions

Tags: r

Consider the dataset:

```
example1 = data.frame("year"=c(1,1,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5),
                   "household"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                   "person"= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                   "expected income" = c(seq(140,260,10)),
                   "income" = c(seq(110,230,10)))
```

Just to have an idea person=1 is the father of the family and person=2 is the mother of the family, in the complete dataset there will be also the children, but it doesn't matter right now.
I need to calculate the ratio between column(4) "expected income" in year(i) and column(5)"income" in year (i+1).
Furthermore the ratio has to be done only when the "person" and "household" is the same.
for example it doesn't have to be calculated the ratio between col(4)-row(4) and col(5)-row(5) because they are two man of different household,
the same for col(5)-row(8) and col(5)-row(9) because they are two different person within the same household.
Instead of the ratio between the "expected income" and the "income" of two different people I need an NA.
It has to be done generically since it is just a semplification of a dataset with more than 60000 row.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to group by household and person, then find the ratio of the expected income to the `lead` value of `income`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

example1 %>%
  group_by(person, household) %>%
  mutate(ratio = expected.income / lead(income))
#> # A tibble: 13 x 6
#> # Groups:   person, household [3]
#>     year household person expected.income income ratio
#>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>           <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1         1      1             140    110  1.17
#>  2     2         1      1             150    120  1.15
#>  3     3         1      1             160    130  1.14
#>  4     4         1      1             170    140 NA   
#>  5     1         2      1             180    150  1.12
#>  6     2         2      1             190    160  1.12
#>  7     3         2      1             200    170  1.11
#>  8     4         2      1             210    180 NA   
#>  9     1         2      2             220    190  1.1 
#> 10     2         2      2             230    200  1.10
#> 11     3         2      2             240    210  1.09
#> 12     4         2      2             250    220  1.09
#> 13     5         2      2             260    230 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
example1 %>%
  mutate(ratio = ifelse(person == household, expected.income/income, NA))
```

Output:

```
   year household person expected.income income    ratio
1     1         1      1             140    110 1.272727
2     1         1      1             150    120 1.250000
3     3         1      1             160    130 1.230769
4     4         1      1             170    140 1.214286
5     1         2      1             180    150       NA
6     2         2      1             190    160       NA
7     3         2      1             200    170       NA
8     4         2      1             210    180       NA
9     1         2      2             220    190 1.157895
10    2         2      2             230    200 1.150000
11    3         2      2             240    210 1.142857
12    4         2      2             250    220 1.136364
13    5         2      2             260    230 1.130435
```

Answer (score 1):

First `order` by household, person and year. Then calculate the ratio and set all rations to `NA` where the next lien is not the next year or not the same household or not the same person.

```
. <- example1
. <- .[order(.$household, .$person, .$year),]
.$ratio <- .$expected.income / c(.$income[-1], NA)
is.na(.$ratio) <- (1 + .$year) != c(.$year[-1], NA) |
  .$household != c(.$household[-1], NA) | .$person != c(.$person[-1], NA)
.
#   year household person expected.income income    ratio
#1     1         1      1             140    110       NA
#2     1         1      1             150    120       NA
#3     3         1      1             160    130 1.142857
#4     4         1      1             170    140       NA
#5     1         2      1             180    150 1.125000
#6     2         2      1             190    160 1.117647
#7     3         2      1             200    170 1.111111
#8     4         2      1             210    180       NA
#9     1         2      2             220    190 1.100000
#10    2         2      2             230    200 1.095238
#11    3         2      2             240    210 1.090909
#12    4         2      2             250    220 1.086957
#13    5         2      2             260    230       NA
```

Don't know if stating two times with year 1 is a typo, but it shows if the condition of next year is considered.